# '' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date (PHP)

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that posts all the gathered information (i.e. when the user enters the details and clicks on submit) it will post to the to a PHP script for processing. The problem is that when I do not pass any value for the date fields, I am getting the error below.

> Error:  '' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date

How can I make my post accept a null value for the fields and successfully submit?

**Form.html**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="CandidateCreationPage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table class="form-table">
 <tbody>
<tr>
 <td class="label-cell"><label>First Name <span class="required-input letters-only">*</span></label></td>
<td>
<input class="required-field letters-only" type="text" name="firstname" id="first-name" maxlength="25" />
 </td>
   </tr>
<tr>
<td class="label-cell"><label>Last Name <span class="required-input">*</span></label></td>
 <td>
 <input class="required-field letters-only" type="text" name="lastname" id="last-name" maxlength="30" />
 </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td class="label-cell"><label>How Did You Learn of This Opportunity? <span class="required-input">*</span></label></td>
<td>
 <select class="required-field" id="hear-this-opportunity" name="hearthisopportunity">
  <option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="Kijiji">Kijiji</option>

</select>
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="label-cell"><label>Please Specify (If Applicable) <span id="please-specify-asterisk" class="required-input hide">*</span></label></td>
 <td>
<input class="letters-only" type="text" name="pleasespecify" id="please-specify" maxlength="50" />
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
 <td class="label-cell"><label>Status</label></td>
  <td>
<select id="status" name="status">
  <option value="">--None--</option>
<option value="Full-time">Full-time</option>     
 </select>
     </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
 <td class="label-cell"><label>Have You Worked With Us Before?</label></td>
  <td>
<select id="worked-previously" name="workedpreviously">
 <option value="">--None--</option>
 <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
 <option value="No">No</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td class="label-cell"><label>When (If Applicable)</label></td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="workedpreviouslywhen" id="worked-previously-when" />
 </td>
</tr>
 <tr>
<td class="label-cell"><label>Available to Start</label></td>
 <td>
 <input type="text" name="availabletostart" id="available-to-start" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Post.PHP**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
try{
$fields = array (
'First_Name__c' => $_POST['firstname'],
'Last_Name__c' => $_POST['lastname'],
'Primary_contact_number__c'=>$_POST['primarycontactnumber'],
'Secondary_contact_number__c'=>$_POST['secondarycontactnumber'],
'Email__c'=> $_POST['email'],
'How_did_you_learn_of_this_Opportunity__c'=>$_POST['hearthisopportunity'],
'Please_Specify__c'=>$_POST['pleasespecify'],
'Status__c'=>$_POST['status'],
'Have_you_worked_with_us_before__c'=>$_POST['workedpreviously'],
'When__c'=>$_POST['workedpreviouslywhen'],
    'Available_to_start__c'=>$_POST['availabletostart'],);
```

Comment: For the date I think you could do isset($_POST['date_name']); I'm not sure but if you don't get an answer by the time I get home I'll try and run this in my xampp.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper : ** Error : '1' is not a valid value for the type xsd:date ** . if we use Isset before posting the variable.

Comment: Oh oops forgot that it would return true. Ignore my comment then. I'll just try and debug it at home.

Comment: @RepeaterCreeper: can anyone help me on this issue...

Comment: I can't figure out why this is not working. Sorry but I can't help you. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as an alternative way You can remove `date` related `variables` from the first array declaration and thereafter You can check if `date` variables are not empty and append them to your `fields` array.

`$fields = array (
'First_Name__c' => $_POST['firstname'],
'Last_Name__c' => $_POST['lastname'],
etc
}`

remove from `$fields` array `variables` like:

```
 ["When__c"]=> 
 ["Available_to_start__c"]
```

and then lets check, and append variables to an array if they are not empty:

```
if(!empty($_POST['When'])){
$fields['When__c'] = $_POST['When'];
}

if(!empty($_POST['AvlToStart'])){
$fields['Available_to_start__c'] = $_POST['AvlToStart'];
}
```

etc

Comment: I have another issue ....with the dates .If i place a value it is not posting the .Instead it is taking the blank for the date

Comment: I'll check it in 30 min.